# Calling a function inside link in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this link function in my directive:

```
link: function (scope) {
    scope.search = function () {
        PessoaService.search(scope.filter, ['nome']).then(function (result) {
            scope.firstList = result.values;
        })
    }
    scope.add = function (pessoa) {
        var index = this.indexOf(pessoa);
        scope.secondList = scope.secondList || [];
        scope.secondList.push(pessoa);
    }

    scope.remove = function (pessoa) {
        var index = this.indexOf(pessoa);
        scope.secondList.splice(index, 1);
    }

    scope.indexOf = function (pessoa) {
        scope.secondList = scope.secondList || [];
        var secondlistAux = scope.secondList;
        for (var i = 0; i < secondlistAux.length; i++) {
            if (secondlistAux[i].id === pessoa.id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    scope.contains = function (pessoa) {
        return this.indexOf(pessoa) >= 0
    }
}
```

how do i call the function scope.search() so i could initialize the array? because i can't see the array before i type something! thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your variables outside of your methods.

```
link: function (scope) {
    scope.firstList = scope.firstList || [];
    scope.secondList = scope.secondList || [];

    scope.search = function () {
        PessoaService.search(scope.filter, ['nome']).then(function (result) {
            scope.firstList = result.values;
        })
    }
    scope.add = function (pessoa) {
        var index = this.indexOf(pessoa);
        scope.secondList.push(pessoa);
    }

    scope.remove = function (pessoa) {
        var index = this.indexOf(pessoa);
        scope.secondList.splice(index, 1);
    }

    scope.indexOf = function (pessoa) {
        var secondlistAux = scope.secondList;
        for (var i = 0; i < secondlistAux.length; i++) {
            if (secondlistAux[i].id === pessoa.id) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    scope.contains = function (pessoa) {
        return this.indexOf(pessoa) >= 0
    }
}
```

---

**update**

You could call `scope.search()` at the end of the `link` function..

```
link: function (scope) {
    /*all the code you have here*/

    // and at the end
   scope.search();
}
```

Comment: i have to call the search function so i could initialize the array. i'm using the ng-change to use the function!